# how to get data from static JSON for table, https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table.iam using ng-2 table

Tags: json, http, angular, ngtable

how to get data from json rather from table-data.ts
iam confused.tried my best cant able to find the solution.where should i do alteration i think from private data:array=TableData;
It will be helpful if anyone give a solution.

Demo.component.ts

```
export class TableDemoComponent implements OnInit { public rows:Array<any> = [];
public columns:Array<any> = [
{title: 'Company', name: 'name', filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by name'}},
{
  title: 'Position',
  name: 'position',
  sort: false,
  filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by position'}
},
{title: 'Location', name: 'office', sort: '', filtering:     {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by Location'}},
{title: 'Date', className: 'text-warning', name: 'startDate'},];
 public page:number = 1;
 public itemsPerPage:number = 10;
 public maxSize:number = 5;
 public numPages:number = 1;
 public length:number = 0;
 public config:any = {

paging: true,
sorting: {columns: this.columns},
filtering: {filterString: ''},
className: ['table-striped', 'table-bordered']
};
private data:Array<any> = TableData;
public constructor() {
this.length = this.data.length;
}
public ngOnInit():void {
this.onChangeTable(this.config);
}
public changePage(page:any, data:Array<any> = this.data):Array<any> {
let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 (startpage.itemsPerPage):data.length;
return data.slice(start, end);
}
public changeSort(data:any, config:any):any {
if (!config.sorting) {
  return data;
}
let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
let columnName:string = void 0;
let sort:string = void 0;
for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {       if(columns[i].sort!==''&&columns[i].sort!==false{columnNamecolumns[i].name;
    sort = columns[i].sort;
  }
}
if (!columnName) {
  return data;
}
// simple sorting
return data.sort((previous:any, current:any) => {
  if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
    return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
  } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
    return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return 0;
  });
  }
  public changeFilter(data:any, config:any):any {
  let filteredData:Array<any> = data;
  this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
  if (column.filtering) {
  filteredData = filteredData.filter((item:any) => {
  return item[column.name].match(column.filtering.filterString); });
  }
  });
 if (!config.filtering) {
  return filteredData;
}
if (config.filtering.columnName) {
  return filteredData.filter((item:any) =>        item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));
}
let tempArray:Array<any> = [];
filteredData.forEach((item:any) => {
  let flag = false;
  this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
    if     (item[column.name].toString().match(this.config.filtering.filterString)) {
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  if (flag) {
    tempArray.push(item);
  }
});
filteredData = tempArray;
return filteredData;
}
public onChangeTable(config:any, page:any = {page:   this.page,itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}):any {
if (config.filtering) {
  Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
}
if (config.sorting) {
  Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
}
let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
this.rows = page && config.paging ?  this.changePage(page,sortedData):sortedData;
this.length = sortedData.length;
}
public onCellClick(data: any): any {
console.log(data);
}}
```

Datatable.ts

```
export const TableData:Array<any> = [
{
'name': 'Victoria Cantrell',
'position': 'Integer Corporation',
'office': 'Croatia',
'ext': `<strong>0839</strong>`,
'startDate': '2015/08/19',
'salary': 208.178
}, {
'name': 'Pearl Crosby',
'position': 'In PC',
'office': 'Cambodia',
'ext': `<strong>8262</strong>`,
'startDate': '2014/10/08',
'salary': 114.367
 }, {
'name': 'Colette Foley',
'position': 'Lorem Inc.',
'office': 'Korea, North',
'ext': '8968',
'startDate': '2015/07/19',
'salary': 721.473
}
];
```

Table-demo.html

```
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
       <input *ngIf="config.filtering" placeholder="Filter allcolumns"
       [ngTableFiltering]="config.filtering"
       class="form-control"
       (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"/>
       </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <ng-table [config]="config"
       (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"
       (cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)"
       [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
        </ng-table>
        <pagination *ngIf="config.paging"
        class="pagination-sm"
        [(ngModel)]="page"
        [totalItems]="length"
        [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"
        [maxSize]="maxSize"
        [boundaryLinks]="true"
        [rotate]="false"
        (pageChanged)="onChangeTable(config, $event)"
        (numPages)="numPages = $event">
        </pagination>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. In comments discussed in below answer you are talking about different things than in your question. Please add where this json file is located, you also mentioned wanting to use http, please add that to question and any other relevant information. If your question is about retrieving JSON from an external file, most of the code you have put in your question is irrelevant. Please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the `TableData` in a different file you would have to import it. I have added an example at the top that show you how to import it. All you do is just create another file and import what you need. I tidied up your code and fixed some syntax errors and put some notes next to bits where stuff was undefined which would throw errors also put some explanations next to the top in how to import things:

```
import {OnInit} from "@angular/core"
import {TableData} from "./test2" //test2 is the name of the file

// ./ current directory
// ../../ up two directories

export class TableDemoComponent implements OnInit {
    public rows: Array<any> = [];

    public columns: Array<any> =
        [
            {
                title: 'Company',
                name: 'name',
                filtering: {
                    filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by name'
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Position',
                name: 'position',
                sort: false,
                filtering: {
                    filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by position'
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Location',
                name: 'office',
                sort: '',
                filtering: {
                    filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by Location'
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Date',
                className: 'text-warning',
                name: 'startDate'
            }
        ];

    public page: number = 1;
    public itemsPerPage: number = 10;
    public maxSize: number = 5;
    public numPages: number = 1;
    public length: number = 0;

    public config: any = {
        paging: true,
        sorting: {columns: this.columns},
        filtering: {filterString: ''},
        className: ['table-striped', 'table-bordered']
    };

    private data: Array<any> = TableData;

    public constructor() {
        this.length = this.data.length;
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onChangeTable(this.config);
    }

    public changePage(page: any, data: Array<any> = this.data): Array<any> {
        let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;

        //startpage is not defined
        let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? startpage.itemsPerPage : data.length;
        return data.slice(start, end);
    }

    public changeSort(data: any, config: any): any {
        if (!config.sorting) {
            return data;
        }

        let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
        let columnName: string = void 0;
        let sort: string = void 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (columns[i].sort !== '' && columns[i].sort !== false) {
                //columnNamecolumns is not defined
                columnNamecolumns[i].name;
                sort = columns[i].sort;
            }
        }

        if (!columnName) {
            return data;
        }

        // simple sorting
        return data.sort((previous: any, current: any) => {
            if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
                return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
                return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }

    public changeFilter(data: any, config: any): any {
        let filteredData: Array<any> = data;
        this.columns.forEach((column: any) => {
            if (column.filtering) {
                filteredData = filteredData.filter((item: any) => {
                    return item[column.name].match(column.filtering.filterString);
                });
            }
        });
        if (!config.filtering) {
            return filteredData;
        }
        if (config.filtering.columnName) {
            return filteredData.filter((item: any) => item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));
        }
        let tempArray: Array<any> = [];
        filteredData.forEach((item: any) => {
            let flag = false;
            this.columns.forEach((column: any) => {
                if (item[column.name].toString().match(this.config.filtering.filterString)) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            });
            if (flag) {
                tempArray.push(item);
            }
        });
        filteredData = tempArray;
        return filteredData;
    }

    public onChangeTable(config: any, page: any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}): any {
        if (config.filtering) {
            Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
        }
        if (config.sorting) {
            Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
        }
        let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
        let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
        this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
        this.length = sortedData.length;
    }

    public onCellClick(data: any): any {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.my above code is working .but i need to display data from external json file using http get.

Comment: @programmernew http? Your question does not mention http at all. What's your backend? Have you read about http in angular.io? Your code is then almost irrelevant to your actual question, as it has nothing to do with http. Consider rephrasing your question completely... You will not receive any useful answers with your current question.

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks.instead of getting data from table-data.ts I want to get it from an external JSON file.can you suggest a way

Comment: @programmernew where is this external JSON located?

Comment: @AJT_82 it is located in assets folder.

Comment: @programmernew, you can make a http call, just like you would to a real api. But instead of using a url, you just write the complete path to your file.

Comment: sorry, bro, you are not getting my question. anyway, thanks :) @AJT_82

Comment: @AJT_82 in above code .. see (demo.component.ts file) . in there private data:Array<any> = TableData; that line getting data from the (data-table.ts) instead i want to get it from a external json using http.get method.

Comment: Well, that code make no sense to me, it has nothing to do with json. If your json-file is in your assets folder, you make a http call, like `this.http.get('path/path/path/assets/file.json').map(res => res.json())` and then do what you want with the json. But maybe as you said, I don't undersstand your question. I must say, it is a bit unclear what you want to do :) You can try to rephrase it and explain to us like we were 2-year-olds, so we surely understand what you mean ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 I think u didn't  get me or u didn't cross this concept I think so.well, we finished it off :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you meant for. I am reading my data from external source (not json - but I think this is the same) by this way:

```
public constructor(private dataService: DataService ){
      this.dataService.getUsers().then(users => {this.data = users; this.length = this.data.length;}).
         catch(error => this.error = error);
  }

  public ngOnInit():void {
       this.dataService.getUsers().then(users => {this.data = users;  this.onChangeTable(this.config);}).
         catch(error => this.error = error);
  }
```

in this example my data is users. I am calling it from my data service. I hope it helps.